# Every 3rd Insert Is Slow On Ms Sql 2008

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a function that writes 3 lines into a empty table like so:

```
INSERT [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] ([GroupID], [ForumID], [AccessMaskID]) VALUES (1, 8, 1) 
INSERT [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] ([GroupID], [ForumID], [AccessMaskID]) VALUES (2, 8, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] ([GroupID], [ForumID], [AccessMaskID]) VALUES (3, 8, 3)
```

For some reason only the third query takes a long time to execute - and with each insert it grows longer.

[Profiler Image http://www.cricut.com/images/SqlQuery.png](http://www.cricut.com/images/SqlQuery.png)
[Profiler Image](http://www.cricut.com/images/SqlQuery.png)

I have tried disabling all constraints on the table - same result. I just can't figure out why the first two would run so fast - and the last one would take so long.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the statistics for a query ran MSSMS:

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
INSERT [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] ([GroupID], [ForumID], [AccessMaskID]) VALUES (1, 9, 1) 
INSERT [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] ([GroupID], [ForumID], [AccessMaskID]) VALUES (2, 9, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] ([GroupID], [ForumID], [AccessMaskID]) VALUES (3, 9, 3)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Stats:

[alt text http://www.cricut.com/images/SqlQuery3.png](http://www.cricut.com/images/SqlQuery3.png)
[Stats](http://www.cricut.com/images/SqlQuery.png)

STATS IO ON:

```
Table 'yaf_vaccess_group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_UserGroup'. Scan count 1, logical reads 709, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_AccessMask'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_Group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_ForumAccess'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'yaf_vaccess_group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 8, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_UserGroup'. Scan count 1, logical reads 709, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_AccessMask'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_Group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_ForumAccess'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'yaf_vaccess_group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 1340999, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 3326, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_UserGroup'. Scan count 1, logical reads 709, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_Group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_AccessMask'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_ForumAccess'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

yaf_vaccess_group View:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[yaf_vaccess_group]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
        select
            b.UserID,
            c.ForumID,
            d.AccessMaskID,
            b.GroupID,
            ReadAccess      = convert(int,d.Flags & 1),
            PostAccess      = convert(int,d.Flags & 2),
            ReplyAccess     = convert(int,d.Flags & 4),
            PriorityAccess  = convert(int,d.Flags & 8),
            PollAccess      = convert(int,d.Flags & 16),
            VoteAccess      = convert(int,d.Flags & 32),
            ModeratorAccess = convert(int,d.Flags & 64),
            EditAccess      = convert(int,d.Flags & 128),
            DeleteAccess    = convert(int,d.Flags & 256),
            UploadAccess    = convert(int,d.Flags & 512),
            DownloadAccess  = convert(int,d.Flags & 1024),
            AdminGroup      = convert(int,e.Flags & 1)
        from
            [dbo].[yaf_UserGroup] b
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[yaf_ForumAccess] c on c.GroupID=b.GroupID
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[yaf_AccessMask] d on d.AccessMaskID=c.AccessMaskID
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[yaf_Group] e on e.GroupID=b.GroupID

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [yaf_vaccess_group_UserForum_PK] ON [dbo].[yaf_vaccess_group] 
(
    [UserID] ASC,
    [ForumID] ASC,
    [AccessMaskID] ASC,
    [GroupID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

STATS IO ON w/ 4 Inserts:

```
Table 'yaf_vaccess_group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_UserGroup'. Scan count 1, logical reads 709, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 7, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_AccessMask'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_Group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_ForumAccess'. Scan count 0, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'yaf_vaccess_group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_UserGroup'. Scan count 1, logical reads 709, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_AccessMask'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_Group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_ForumAccess'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'yaf_vaccess_group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 1220894, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_UserGroup'. Scan count 1, logical reads 709, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_Group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_AccessMask'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_ForumAccess'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'yaf_vaccess_group'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_UserGroup'. Scan count 1, logical reads 709, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_AccessMask'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'yaf_ForumAccess'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: nice try with the screenshot - at least I can not enlarge it at all, so it is not usefull at all, sadly.

Comment: right click - view image or equivalent.

Comment: [I've added a direct link to the image] Do you see the same behaviour when inserting records using T-SQL in SSMS? If so, is there any difference between the query plans of the "slow" and "fast" versions? Are all batches inserting the same number of records?

Comment: Yes - I just restored the database (so the table in question is again empty). It took ~30 seconds to complete. http://www.cricut.com/images/SqlQuery2.png

Comment: More information needed.  The figures presented in SQL Profiler can sometimes be misleading.  I'd definitely want to know whether this behaviour is noticable as a user (is the third action always much slower than the previou two?) and whether it can be replicated via "manual" SQL in SSMS.  What does the output say if you SET STATISTICS IO ON?  What does the query plan say (even if there's no difference)?

Comment: Yea, its only three inserts at a time. There is something like 200 or so batches. The only thing that changes is the ForumID - everything else is static.

Comment: The most recent image suggests those three records were inserted in 143ms which is a far cry from the 30s suggested by Profiler.  Have you ever seen it *actually* take 30 seconds to insert 3 records rather than just seen a figure in Profiler?

Comment: Yea - it takes that long. The total execution time in SSMS showed 33 seconds.

Comment: OK, the STATS IO output has convinced me!  Are there any triggers on yaf_vaccess_group?

Comment: Just noticed the difference in logical reads on yaf_vaccess_group. This looks like a view that inner joins with the table I'm inserting to.

Comment: Nope - no triggers dbo.yaf_vaccess_group or dbo.yaf_ForumAccess

Comment: Added the view create sql for reference.

Comment: This is odd.  I've downloaded YAF and had a look over the database build scripts.  There don't appear to be any indexed views and the only trigger is unrelated.  The very large number of reads suggests maybe an index is getting rebuilt (but if so, why?) or that a very poor row-per-row query is happening somehow.  I guess the next step is to look at the query plans: both slow and fast versions.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So is that the same thing as the execution plan?

Comment: Yes, the query plan an execution pan are the same thing but see Chris Lively's answer.

Comment: Copuld you please check that there really are no indexes and no triggers on yaf_vaccess_group in your installation?

Comment: There are no triggers - but there is an index. I'll add it above.

Comment: Added to the end of the create sql.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's the index that's causing this.  See my answer.

Comment: Daniel Renshaw was spot with his answer. I tried recreating the table with index padding - but the result was the same. In the end I have decided to drop that view. The import ran all 200+ batches in a few seconds. Not sure why this is a issue - but I'll just recreate the logic in the business logic layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably caused by the index on the view vaccess_group.  Because the view has no padding, adding records will require SQL Server to split the index frequently and it may be that after every third index it fees that an index rebuild is the most optimal way t maintain the index structure/performance.

Try adding some padding to the index.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx for info.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [yaf_vaccess_group_UserForum_PK] ON [dbo].[yaf_vaccess_group]
( 
    [UserID] ASC, 
    [ForumID] ASC, 
    [AccessMaskID] ASC, 
    [GroupID] ASC
)
WITH
(
    PAD_INDEX = ON,  -- CHANGE HERE
    FILLFACTOR = 50, -- AND HERE
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

BTW, the reason I failed to spot this index in the YAF database build scripts is because, annoyingly, it's *not* in indexes.sql.  For some reason they've put all view indexes into constraints.sql instead!

Comment: Wow, cant believe you went to that length to help me out. I'll post back with the results later. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

From what you've shown, it's not the third query that is taking the time, its the part that is actually turning on the check constraints.

When the constraint is turned back on it has to validate that all of the records are good.  This means scanning the entire table.  Depending on size, it's probably IO bound and beating the crap out of your harddrives.

So, I think you need to make a decision.  Either drop the constraints completely or stop flipping them on and off.

Comment: Now you point it out, it's obvious!  When Chris wrote "I have tried disabling all constraints on the table - same result". I, probably inappropriately, assumed this was happening even without the ALTER TABLE statements.  But I think you're right.

Comment: Nope - it happen with the check constrains removed. I just put those in to make it easier to test. Also when I step through the code its always that 3rd insert that stalls for awhile.

Comment: Well - let me turn it back off and test again

Comment: Yep - same result. ~30 seconds on the 3rd insert.

Comment: Can you add a 4th query to the bunch and test that?

Comment: Now I'm thinking it may have to do with the transaction being committed.

Comment: How many rows are there in this table (or the linked view).  This many reads suggsts a very large mount of data - is that true?

Comment: Without an explicit BEGIN/END TRAN, each insert would be in it's own implicit transaction so there should't be any difference betwen the three.

Comment: 4th insert ran fine - stats added above. There is nothing in this table to start with - but yes there are ~800k rows in the dbo.yaf_vaccess view. I guess I never connected that the one table was using the other.